# Looking to optimize graphics performance on my PC

Tags: windows-7, upgrade

I have and Intel Core 2 Duo e6550 @ 2.33ghz, 3 GB dual channel DDR2@399 and a Nvidia 1536mb GeForce  8600 GT.  I am running windows 7 32 bit home premium.  I around $100 to do an component upgrade.  What would be the best bang for my buck?  What would the possibility of overclocking be?  Any free suggestions would be great also.  Looking for better performance in games and in video playback quality.  Thanks.

Comment: What sort of C2D?

Comment: Optimize graphics? A little more details please, is the Aero interface slow, or do you wanna get better graphics at games or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you can cough up another $40, i'd recommend a Radeon 5xxx series with **DirectX 11 support**, entry level models are available for $140, like this **[Radeon HD 5750](http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=5316155&CatId=3669)** with **1GB GDDR5** memory:

[image]

Comment: So you would recommend a new video card over more ram?

Comment: 3 GB RAM is fine for windows 7, more system memory will hardly improve the graphics performance. and if i had to invest into a new graphics card now, i'd make sure it supports directX 11.

Comment: Great I guess that is what I will do.

Answer (score 3):

With around a 100 dollars you could easily bring your graphics card in to the current generation. A 9800GT wouldn't hurt?

Or you could look at some of their newer chipsets.

But looking at your current configuration i would probably say a new video card is the best bet. More things rely on the video card rather then the CPU these days (assuming you are graphics/video editing or playing games)

Hope that helped!

Comment: So you would recommend a new video card over more ram?

Comment: Easily. You have sufficient RAM for most computer operations! The video card will be the most noticeable performance change for your situation in my opinion!

Comment: Great I guess that is what I will do.

Answer (score 0):

thats REAL easy to say "JUST BUY A NEW ONE" But the man asked to beef up his current one.  For this card EVGA percision turner will OVERCLOCK your GPU;Shaders;and memory on the card.  USING this software you can EASLY give your card the SAME clock speeds as these others cards that are covited so much.. EXAMPLE i have  a 8200m G IGP for my laptop. Stock speeds  400 gpu 800 shader 667 ddr2 memory. i have it clocked to 580 GPU 1.3 Ghz shader and 800 mhz ram on the INTERNAL card. JUST like a more expensive card. SO i have 40-60 fps instead of 20-30 fps.  IF you don't have any money LIKE ME. then this can be a solution for you.